Filtering an HTMLDropDownListFor depending on the ID
I want to be able to filter this dropdownlistfor where it will only display the items in a collection where the MemoId is 0
so far what I've done is this:
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MemoTeplateId, new SelectList(ViewBag.lstSacntion.Where(Model => Model.MemoId == 0),"Id", "Name"), "-- Select Disciplinary --", new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" }

it shows me an error that says CS1977, but clicking the error link doesn't show me any information besides the tooltip saying "Cannot use lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The compiler does not know what ViewBag.lstSacntion is supposed to be. You need to cast it to the correct class and it will work.
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MemoTeplateId, 
    new SelectList(((List<WebApplication1.Models.Sanction>)ViewBag.lstSacntion).Where(Model => Model.MemoId == 0),"Id", "Name"), "-- Select Disciplinary --", new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" }

Or you could add the list to the Model itself since you so seem to use one.
public class HomeViewModel
{
     public List<WebApplication1.Models.Sanction> lstSacntion { get; set; }
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MemoTeplateId, 
    new SelectList(Model.lstSacntion.Where(Model => Model.MemoId == 0),"Id", "Name"), "-- Select Disciplinary --", new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" }

